# How to make flash builder component affect main application?

Tags: actionscript-3, parent-child, flash-builder, custom-component

I have my main application, which contains several instances of a component that create a grid of photos belonging to a certain category. (the grids, and the photos are created dynamically with a loop).

I'd like to be able to click a photo to run a function that loads the large version of the photo into a separate element that is contained in the main application. So I created a Photo component in my main application, but how, using actionscript, do I change the 'currentphoto' variable in my main application from inside the tileview component?

Alternately I could put the function in the main application (probably more logical in the long run), but how would I call it from the child component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would dispatch a Event.SELECT event in the tileview when a photo is selected that the main application adds an event listener for. The tileview should have a selectedImage property or something similar so that the main app can determine what image to load in the photo component when it receives an event.

Comment: I have a selectedImage property and I can get it to change within the tileview on selectedIndex change (made tileview into a list..) i'm not sure exactly how to listen for a change from the main window though.

Comment: Since your tileview is a control, I'm guessing it extends `EventDispatcher` (if not, you can implement the `IEventDispatcher` interface. That means you should have two public methods as members to your class, `dispatchEvent` and `addEventListener`. The [Adobe docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html) give an example, but if you need another one, I can add some code to my answer.

Comment: it doesn't extend eventdispatcher.. it's not actually extending anything right now, so i guess I could make it do that. I'll have a look at that article and see what I can come up with. thanks.